# Retrieve subsites from site collection sort last modified date using CSOM

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model

I want to retrieve subsites from current site collection. And it should be order by last item modified date.

I am able to retrieve subsites by following code :

```
channel_context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
channel_web = channel_context.get_web();
channel_context.load(channel_web);

webCollection = channel_web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
channel_context.load(webCollection)
channel_context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
var temp = ""; 
var webEnumarator = webCollection.getEnumerator();
var i = 0;
while(webEnumarator.moveNext()){
   var curWeb = webEnumarator.get_current();
   temp = temp+"<br/>"+curWeb.get_title();
   webArray[i] = curWeb.get_title();
   i++;
}
document.getElementById("sliderDiv").innerHTML = temp;
}, onSliderImageLoadFailed);
```

But the webs which I am getting are sort by its title. Which I want to sort by Last Item Modified Date.
Is there any other option for sorting?
Do I have to manually apply some logic for sorting?

Comment: If you use the REST API you can do the get and the order by in one call.  /_api/Web/Webs?$orderby=LastItemModifiedData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to return web sites sorted by last modified date:

```
function getWebs(success,error) 
{
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var webs = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
    ctx.load(webs);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            var result = [];
            for(var i = 0;i < webs.get_count();i++) {
               var web = webs.get_item(i);
               result.push(web);
            }
            result.sort(compareByLastModifiedDate);
            success(result);
        },
        error);
}

//sorting function with modifications from answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1129270/1375553
function compareByLastModifiedDate(a,b) {
  if (a.get_lastItemModifiedDate() < b.get_lastItemModifiedDate())
     return -1;
  if (a.get_lastItemModifiedDate() > b.get_lastItemModifiedDate())
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Usage

```
getWebs(function(webs){
    for(var i = 0;i < webs.length;i++){
        console.log(webs[i].get_lastItemModifiedDate());
    }
},
function(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

Key points:

- [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method is used for sorting the web objects array

Comment: Nice. PS: Instead of the webs.get_count loop, you could have done: var result = webs.get_data();

Comment: Indeed, it's more elegant way of getting an array of objects. Thanks Anders!